# Multiple servers in spark-defaults.conf

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera

I have a Cloudera (Cloudera Express 5.4.1 (#197 built by jenkins on 20150509-0041 git: `003e06d761f80834d39c3a42431a266f0aaee736`)) with Spark installed on it. I want the spark-defaults.conf to have 2 servers defined. How do we carry it out?

```
spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://XXXX:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://XXXX:18088
```

I want it to be like

```
spark.eventLog.dir={hdfs://XXXX:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory,hdfs://YYYY:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory}
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.yarn.historyServer.address={http://XXXX:18088, http://YYYY:18088}
```

Comment: Why do you need two spark History servers?

Comment: Scenarios wherein one server goes down ..